# IF statement truth condition

Tags: if-statement, python-3.x

I made a function that verify if the user argument follow the rules(only words with A,B,C,D letters).

```
for letter in var:
    if letter == 'A' or letter == 'C' or letter == 'C' or letter == 'D':
        return True
    elif letter == "~" or letter == "!" or letter == "#" or letter == "$" or letter == "%" or letter == "^" or letter == "&" or letter == "*":
        return False
    else:
        return False
```

My problem is about the "~!@#$%^&*" charachters. If I enter in the shell:

> > > function("A&BCD"), the result is True.

What is the problem?

Comment: you check for letter C twice but letter B not once.

Answer (score 6):

The function iterates over the string from the beginning, so it considers `'A'` first. `'A'` satisfies the first condition, so the function returns `True`. It doesn't keep going, because `return` immediately ends the function containing the `return` statement.

If you want your function to only return `True` if *all* the input characters are valid, don't return in the valid case until you've checked all the characters:

```
for letter in var:
    if letter not in 'ABCD':
        # The input contains an invalid character; return immediately.
        return False
    # Otherwise, everything we've checked so far is OK, but the rest of the
    # string might contain invalid characters. Keep going.

# The string had no invalid characters.
return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment/Uncomment the print line at the end for your version of python

```
def check_format(check_string):
    validated = True
    bad_letters = "~!@#$%^&*"
    for letter in bad_letters:
        if letter in check_string:
            validated = False
            break
    if validated:
        good_letters = "ABCD"
        for letter in check_string:
            if not letter in good_letters:
                validated = False
                break
    return validated


print(check_format("A&BCD")) #python 3
#print check_format("A&BCD") #python 2
```

the part where we check for bad letters is redundant as well, as user2357112's answer shows, but I put it in there to show you how to do it.